# WCAG 2.0: Difference between Technique H44 and Technique F68

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag

Could someone explain the difference between [Technique H44](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html) and [Technique F68](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F68.html) ?

They relate to the same set of instruction and seem quite identical to me.

Comment: Failure Techniques are a 100% **certain** way to fail a WCAG 2.0 criterion. Other Techniques aren't normative: there may have other ways of still meeting this criterion. In the particular example of H44: by using a title attribute on a form element instead of a label asssociated with `for`, etc. Labels are better but WCAG 2.0 is OK with the use of `title`

Answer (score 2):

H44 describes a way to pass a number of success criterion.

F68 demonstrates various common things people do in *failed* efforts to present information that should be in a label through some other method. These methods have problems which result in two of those criterion not being met.